# sending all data from email with require field

Tags: php, email

I'm creating a user require form in my site. For this I put some validation on compulsory fields, and when a user fills in the form and presses submit and validation is correct then I receive a email on my email address.

But now I would like all user information in the email, like name, city, budget etc... so what changes do I need to make in my email.php script?

If some fields are not compulsory and the user doesn't fill them in, can they affect my script?

My script is:

```
<?php

  $to = "test@networkers.in";
  $subject = "a new requiremnet come!";
  $message = "Hi,\n\nyou get a new require";

  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Sender-IP: " . $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: " . stripslashes($name) . " <" . $email . ">" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Priority: normal" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

  $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ;

  if ($sent) {
    echo "Your mail was sent successfully";
  } else {
    echo "We encountered an error sending your mail";
  }

?>
```

and the data I recieve is:

```
$name = $_POST['fname'].' '.$_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['mail'];
$phone = $_POST['ph'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$pt = $_POST['pt'];
$cwl = $_POST['cwl'];
$dyhyows = $_POST['dyhyows'];
$pb = $_POST['pb'];
$bpd = $_POST['bpd'];
$hdyhau = $_POST['hdyhau'];
```

Comment: is this how you indent your code or just a display problem? and also: what is the real question here? if you can concatenate the values you have in post to your $message?

Comment: hoe can i add this info with $message?

Comment: the way it is done for the $headers variable could be an option. you have the initial line $message = "Hi,\n\nyou get a new require"; and you can keep adding values like $message .= "\n Name: " .$name; and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add fields to the message body by concatenating them like so:

```php
$message = "Hi,\n\nyou get a new require";
$message .= "\n Name:    " . $name;
$message .= "\n Email:   " . $email;
$message .= "\n Phone:   " . $phone;
$message .= "\n Country: " . $country;
$message .= "\n pt:      " . $pt;
$message .= "\n cwl:     " . $cwl;
$message .= "\n dyhyows: " . $dyhyows;
$message .= "\n pb:      " . $pb;
$message .= "\n bpd:     " . $bpd;
$message .= "\n hdyhau:  " . $hdyhau
```

Any fields that weren’t filled in by the user will simply be blank.